# Error while changing hard coded file to user prompted file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file to an Excel sheet.

I recorded a macro. The macro uses a hard coded file.

```
Sub ImportData()
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="XX", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""N:\Operations\Workshop\04 Turbine Testing\01 Engine Test Data\SN140\Build01\Data\Raw\OPC data\SN140-01-07 250kW test.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=104, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.Tra" & _
        "nsformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Timestamp"", type datetime}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.Engine_Shaft_Power"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.HT80"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PT80"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99" & _
        "_Signals.TE80"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]SE210A"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]SE210B"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]SE210C"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]SY210"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.Engine_Inlet_Mass_Flow"", type number}, {""[I00001" & _
        "9_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.FT912"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PDT110"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PT925"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PT931"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PT980A" & _
        """, type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PT980B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE130A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE130B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE970"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0" & _
        "_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE971"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE972"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE973"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT364A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT364B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT375"", " & _
        "type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT376"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PY364"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE141A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE141B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE142A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE142B"", type number}, {" & _
        """[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE143A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE143B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE144A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE144B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]ZT370"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]FV370"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testce" & _
        "ll_Heng_Rev_0_12]FV370B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TT371"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT360"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]ZT361"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]FV361"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]FV361B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]ZT" & _
        "366"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]FV366"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]FV366B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.FT933A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE940"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE941"", type nu" & _
        "mber}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE942"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE943"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE944"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE945"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB" & _
        "99_Signals.TE946"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE947"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE948"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE949"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE950"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testce" & _
        "ll_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PDT953"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PDT954"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PDT955"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PDT956"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE161"", type number}, {""[I000" & _
        "019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE162"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE163"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE164"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE165"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE166"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TY160"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Re" & _
        "v_0_12]PT160"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.Turbine_Entry_Temperature"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]VY210"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]VY215"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]VY220"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT240"", type number}, {""[I00" & _
        "0019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE231"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT231"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE233"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]PT381"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:Flame_Monitoring.BT_DERV01.Out"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signa" & _
        "ls.PT130A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.PT130B"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE951"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE952"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE110A"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE110B""," & _
        " type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]TE362"", type number}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY218"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY219"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY221"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY222" & _
        """, Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY223"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY224"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]FT234"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]FT235"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:Combustor_Vibration_Signals.VY141A"", " & _
        "Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:Combustor_Vibration_Signals.VY141B"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:Combustor_Vibration_Signals.VY142A"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:Combustor_Vibration_Signals.VY142B"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY2161"", Int64.T" & _
        "ype}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB88_Signals.VY2171"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.Gas_Fuel_Mass_Flow"", Int64.Type}, {""[I000019_Testcell_Heng_Rev_0_12]Program:TB99_Signals.TE929"", type number}, {"""", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add


    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location= ""XX""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [XX]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "XX"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With

    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

I want to replace the hard coded file in the code with a user prompted file, hence added the following code to the above.

```
Dim path As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="XX", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents (path).... remaining code as it was
```

This gives an error in the line `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`.

Comment: Hi there, you have put .refresh backgroundquery = false, can you just comment it out as any way its not refreshing

Comment: I tried commenting that... this time no error but the data is not imported. The initial code works fine and it creates problem only when i change the path (string) as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to ask for clarification so here goes...

When I want to get a user-selected file I use something like this. I'll modify the context to refer to a CSV for this case:

```
    Dim importFile as String

    'Displays an open file dialog box for selecting the target file.
    importFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="CSV Files, *.csv; Title:="Select a CSV file")

    'Handles no sheet selection.
    If importFile = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No File Selected!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

From there you can use importFile as the path. Try this

```
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(importFile)...
```

Comment: I get the following error "run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error" at the  .refresh backgroundquery = false line

Comment: The issue is when i add the variable 'importFile' in Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(importFile)...I run the macro and i get "run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error" at the .refresh backgroundquery = false line. But If i give the actual file location in Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""N:\Operations\Workshop\04 Turbine Testing\01 Engine Test Data\SN140\Build01\Data\Raw\OPC data\SN140-01-07 250kW test.csv"")...., then the macro works like a gem

Answer (score 0):

This should get it done.

```
"let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(" & """" & importFile & """" & "),[Delimiter=""#(tab)"", ...
```